# SQL to retrieve id that match the highest date, grouped by another field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following data:

[image]

I want to retrieve the `ids` that match the highest date (represented by `max(folga)`), grouping by `funcionario_id`.

Here's the output table I want, **but it's missing the id**:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?  Also, what are you getting instead of the expected output?  What do you mean by `but it's missing the id`?

Comment: If you looked on google at all, it is a simple [GROUP BY clause](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx).   `SELECT funcionario_id, MAX(folga) FROM yourTableName GROUP BY funcionario_id;`

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it seems like you didn't understand. The second image I sent returns exactly what your query suggest, but like I said, I want the id field that matches the highest date in the output.

Comment: I'm glad someone helped you on this, but me not understanding is exactly why you needed to provide a better-formed question. Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You may also benefit from [this helpful article on what is considered necessary for an SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select
  t.funcionario_id, t.folga, t.id
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where funcionario_id = t.funcionario_id and folga > t.folga
)
```

or you can `group by funcionario_id` first to get the max date (I guess this is the query that returned the result you posted) and then join to the table:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join (
  select funcionario_id, max(folga) folga
  from tablename
  group by funcionario_id 
) g on g.funcionario_id = t.funcionario_id and g.folga = t.folga
```

Comment: Thank you forpas! I was having a hard time figuring out how to do it. It took me a while to understand your first solution. I'm gonna test both and mark the answer later.